# PhysX character kinematic library

Tags: physx

I am trying to use PhysX character kinematic, but I got to problem right at start. When I create the controller manager like this:

```
nxManager = PxCreateControllerManager( *nxFoundation );
```

which is at the end of my PhysX initialization function, but I get error:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PxCreateControllerManager referenced in function "void __cdecl InitPX(void)" (?InitPX@@YAXXZ)
```

I do have PhysX3CharacterKinematic.lib linked in, I have tried rebuilding it from the SDK with various options (debug, release, ...) but I still can't get it to work. Any idea what might be wrong there? I am running PhysX SDK 3.1.2

Comment: okay solved, need to add PX_PHYSX_CHARACTER_STATIC_LIB to preprocessor definition list

Comment: You should have put this as an answer. I would have upvoted it. Thanks!